# Как удалить из ArrayList элемент?

Tags: android, arraylist

Подскажите как удалить в arraylist элемент от 0 до того элемента который содержит определенное значение.

```
 for(int i = 0; i < address.size(); i++){
        if(address.get(i).contains(address.get(count_maidan))) {
```

//// вот тут надо указать что от  0 и до  address.get(i).contains(address.get(count_maidan) надо очистить список
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Котлин принимается?

```
val address = arrayListOf("abc", "qwe", "rty", "iop", "asd")
val index = address.indexOfFirst { it.contains("r") } // 2
val newAddress = address.takeLast(address.size - index - 1) // [iop, asd]
```

Comment: Если можно то на Java )))

Comment: Спасибо! На котлин тоже помогло, понял смысл